# Mailing reports with AWS

Tags: civireport, aws

If you use AWS and try mailing a report to multiple emails it fails with:

> Mailing Error Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code
> received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by
> a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the
> settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email
> (SMTP). (code: 554, response: Transaction failed: Domain contains
> illegal character)]

Under `Email Delivery`, it does not like the comma in the comma separated format that is supposed to be used for multiple email addresses.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put one email in the TO field but as many as you like in comma separated format in the CC field.

[image]

Not sure if there is configuration necessary in AWS to change this behavior but heads up for those on AWS.